# Unable to set valuemember/display member to bind combobox

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, combobox

I'm having trouble adding dynamically a combo box column to my datagridview (before you ask, yes it must be dynamic and not done in editor).

The main feature is that the combobox cell is different for each row, so it must be done using combo box cell. checkedRows is a datatable.

Name of the datagridview is editCameraTable. It already has a few columns at this point:

```
'create new column
            Dim resComboColumn As New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn _
                With {.HeaderText = "Resolution", .ReadOnly = False, .DisplayIndex = 7, .Name = "Resolution", _
                      .DisplayMember = "Name", .ValueMember = "ID", .DataPropertyName = "ID"}

           'add combo box column 

            EditCameras.editCameraTable.Columns.Insert(17, resComboColumn)
            addResCmbBox(checkedRows, resComboColumn)
```

Pretty straight forward. You'll notice I have the value member, dataproperty name, etc. Here's the addResCmbBox definition:

```
Public Function addResCmbBox(ByRef DT As DataTable, column As DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)

    Dim resolutions As String()
    'for each camera 
    For i As Integer = 0 To DT.Rows.Count - 1

        Dim camera As camera = convertDTtoCam(DT, i)

        'get the resarray 
        Select Case DT.Rows(i).Item("Maker").ToString.ToLower

            Case "acti"
                resolutions = ACTi.GetResArray(camera)
            Case Else
                resolutions = ACTi.GetResArray(camera)
        End Select

        'add items to combobox list 
        Dim comboCell As New DataGridViewComboBoxCell

        comboCell.DataSource = resolutions

        For j As Integer = 0 To resolutions.Length - 1

            'set to current resolution value
            If resolutions(j).TrimStart("N") = camera.res Then
                comboCell.Value = resolutions(j)

            End If

        Next
        comboCell.DisplayMember = "Name"
        comboCell.ValueMember = "ID"
        EditCameras.editCameraTable("Resolution", i) = comboCell


    Next
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

camera is a structure. I have no problems until I get to the displayMember and value member problem, i.e. the last line starting with "editcameras.editcameratable...".

When doing so, the exception of "The Field Name does not exist" pops up. If I don't assign the displayMember and valueMember, I have no problems. But, I can't get the value selected in the comboBox (it comes back as Null). At runtime, the combobox column has the valuemember and display name as "ID" and "Name".

How can I bind this comboboxcell to the row so that I can later get it's selected value?

**UPDATE:**

I did as was commented, and created a struct/class that was meant to be the resolution property:

```
 Public Class ResolutionStruct
 Property Name As String
 Property ID As String
 End Class
```

And within the loop I create a list of this class, and assign the values to it:

```
      Dim resolutionList As New List(Of ACTi.ResolutionStruct)

        For j As Integer = 0 To resolutions.Length - 1

            Dim resClass As New ACTi.ResolutionStruct
            resClass.Name = resolutions(j)
            resClass.ID = resolutions(j)
            resolutionList.Add(resClass)


        Next

        'set combocell values
        comboCell.DisplayMember = "Name"
        comboCell.ValueMember = "ID"
        comboCell.DataSource = resolutionList

        EditCameras.editCameraTable("Resolution", i) = comboCell
```

However, the comboboxCell doesn't show any value when it drops down. So, now I've bound the values but it shows nothing. Is there anything else I should be doing so that I get both the holy combo of seeing the values I'm picking AND having them be bound to the data grid view? :D

**UPDATE 2** 
So, mea culpa. I was adding the combobox cell to the wrong column!

So now, it is showing the values. I click a value, and try to grab the selected value as as string:

```
  Dim cmbbox2 As DataGridViewComboBoxCell = editCameraTable("Resolution", i)
                 resolution(i) = cmbbox2.Selected.ToString()
```

But it still says it's a null value! Mid build I checked the combobox props. IN fact "selected" is a boolean as false.  It has no value, says it has no items as well. Any ideas on why it says it is null?

**UPDATE3**:

I recently resorted a different column in the table, and the values from the combo box are cleared! I guess it's really never being attached/bound in the first place.

**UPDATE4**:

Fixed it!!

Apparently this line: 
     editCameraTable.Sort(editCameraTable.Columns("ID"), System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending)

Caused the table to freak out! I can now get the value (woohoo!)

Comment: Are Name and ID Properties? thus: Property Name as String and not Public Name as String

Comment: I don't understand what you're getting at. I have set the displayMember and valuemember as "Resolution" as well and it would say that property field doesn't exist (done so separately).

Comment: Ah my bad, I figured you added the Camera objects to the Combobox. Didn't read it through to realise that your were adding an array of strings. So disregard my first comment, I'll see if I can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, I'll try to explain this shortly:

DisplayMember and ValueMember are supposed to be set using properties. For example you create a class containing Name and ID

```
Public Class Test
  Property Name as String
  Property ID as String
End Class
```

Create a few of these objects and put them in a list. Set the list as the datasource to the combobox. Now you can access the DisplayMember and ValueMember as you have written it in your code. Value would be the ID and SelectedItem would be the entire class.

What you are doing now is that you are adding a list of strings to the combobox. A String does not contain the Property Name nor ID, so naturally you can't fetch them. See it like this:

To be able to use Value and/or DisplayMember you need to be able to fetch the Property by yourself. In this case:

```
resolutions(j).Name 
or 
resolutions(j).ID
```

This does not work.

But for example you would be able to do this:

```
resolutions(j).Length
```

So You would be able to do this, which would display the Length in the combobox:

```
Combobox.DisplayMember = "Length"
```

To currently get the value you would have to do:

```
Combobox.SelectedItem.ToString()
```

But since you have it in a combobox column My guess is that this won't cut it since you can't fetch the value from the DataGridView.

**EDIT:** You are still doing this right?

```
<DataGridView>.Item("Resolution", i) = comboCell
```

Otherwise you will have empty comboboxes.

**EDIT2:** No need to fetch value from Combobox, get it from Grid cell instead:

```
<DataGridView>.Item("Resolution", i).Value
```

When creating the columns don't forget to set a defaultvalue to the combobox, otherwise it might be Nothing:

```
comboCell.DisplayMember = "Name"
comboCell.ValueMember = "ID"
comboCell.Value = resolutions(0)
```

Comment: Ah, I see what you're trying to say here, now. Yeah, basically the problem is the value never binds to the dataGridView. Do you suggest that I declare the Name and ID property prior to the column creation and then use the same code to grab the values? Or do I need to add those properties to the resolutions array/make a resolutions struct?

Comment: Create a classitem (test) for each resolution. Set name and id to be  resolution(j). Then the list of classes as datasource and you shiuldbe fine.

Comment: Yep, EditCameras.editCameraTable("Resolution", i) = comboCell after I set the value member. I did the grid cell as well, still a null exception. I added it to the question code.

Comment: This returns a nothing string: `Dim x As String = editCameraTable.Rows(0).Cells("Resolution").Value`. P.S. your help has been great so far.

Comment: added 'comboCell.Value = resolutions(0)' no luck. It does return that the comboboxcell's valuetype as "System.Object" and the value.string is 'Nothing'. I'll edit the question to show what I have done.